# JavaScript or jQuery on html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

This is as clear as I know how to be with this issue. I've done what research I can on fixing it, and since it is someone else' work being modified it's hard to find what to do. I am nowhere near proficient enough to do this on my own. Sorry if it's not clear enough!

This theme is no longer supported even though it's pretty new [my-horse.com.au](http://my-horse.com.au). At the top of the page when you hover on the search icon a search area drops down and shows a search area with a few select boxes.

This is the basic on how the form is set up. #search-hover contains #search and #search contains the form. The only issue happens on the select boxes, not standard input boxes.

```
<div id="search-hover" style="height: 70px;">
  <div id="search">
    <form id="search-spots" action="http://my-horse.com.au" method="post">
  <span id="finish-filter" class="responsive-only"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Finish Filtering</span>
  <div class="large-4 columns" id="search-form-column-1">
    <label class="sf_if_1222">Country</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="has_changed_country" id="has_changed_country" value="false">
    <div class="select-replace parent-1222 sf_if_1222 type-dropdown">
      <select name="country" class="parent-1222 sf_if_1222 type-dropdown" onchange="jQuery('#has_changed_country').val('true');  jQuery('#search-spots').submit(); jQuery('#has_changed_country').val('false');" style="display: block; opacity: 0;">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="587">Australia</option>
        <option value="3270">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="2471">United States</option>
        <option value="1409">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="4103">France</option>
        <option value="4291">Germany</option>
        <option value="1291">Italy</option>
        <option value="3322">Spain</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue only exists in IE (hahah) as far as I've seen. I've tried a few things using JS to fix the issue, but I'm not very good with it. What happens is when you click the select box and hover over anythin in the dropdown list, the whole search area slides back up.
This is some of the different scripts I've tried without any results yet.

```
onMouseEnter="document.getElementById('search-hover').style.height = '281px';
onMouseExit="document.getElementById('search-hover').style.height = '70px';
onMouseOver="document.getElementById('search-hover').style.height = '281px';
onMouseOut="document.getElementById('search-hover').style.height = '70px';
onFocus="document.getElementById('search-hover').style.height = '281px';
$("#search select").mouseenter(function () {
$('#search-hover').css({"height","281px"});
});

$("#search select").mouseleave(function () {
$('#search-hover').css({"height", "70px"});
});
```

and this is the jQuery that I think controls the search area

http://pastebin.com/m3J9DLNH

Can anyone help me with where I might be going wrong or point me in the right direction?

My idea is something like this -

`onFocus = get.elementId('search select')` then something that tells the CSS for `#search-hover` to set the `height` to `281px`

something that will run through the whole site easy enough. From what I've read on different forums, IE leaves the 'div' area when it enters the drop down area in a form . I'm not really sure why but it is apparently something that happens a lot. I'm basing what I've found on this
[IE select issue with hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702354/ie-select-issue-with-hover)
which I tried to figure out how to implement in to my form, but don't know how since I'm not any good with JS.

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: Hi, which version of IE do you encounter the issue with?

Comment: I've only been able to test with IE11 so far. Your reply below helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is already some code in the plugin to try and correct this issue.
Unfortunately, the code tries to detect IE and fails as the detection method is no more working with recent versions of IE.

Try and update the code `navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") != -1` in `searchShowOnHover` with `navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("trident/") != -1`.

Comment: That worked almost perfectly! The only issue is that now when I leave the whole search area the dropdown doesn't go back up lol. Maybe there's an issue with onmouseexit or onmouseout?

Comment: `if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") !== -1 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("trident/") != -1)`
is how I have it now

Comment: You mean you removed the `find("select:focus").length > 0` part?

Comment: Ok I can see you added the test with trident at the end. You need to add parenthesis then: `if(e.find("select:focus").length>0&&(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie")!=-1||navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("trident/") != -1))`

Comment: awesome, perfect! One last question. I changed this one part as well because it had the msie test in it. Do I need to add any extra parenthesis?
`if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") !== -1 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("trident/") != -1) {
    // Try to avoid IE timeout when processing a huge number of markers:
    this.batchSize_ = this.batchSizeIE_;
  }

  this.setupStyles_();

  this.addMarkers(opt_markers, true);
  this.setMap(map); // Note: this causes onAdd to be called
}`

Comment: If this is the exact code, it should work fine this way. In the previous example, there was `(a && b || c)`; without parenthesis, it returns true if a and b are true, or if c is true (because && has priority against ||). We added parenthesis to make sure a is true + b or c is true